# How to use Constructor Injection on Spring 3.2.9?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, cglib, constructor-injection

to everybody click my question, thank you(my eng is bad).

The spring version Im working on is 3.2.9.
And it's been used Field Injection like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/something")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

}
```

But Recently, I knew Using the Constructor Injection is way safey and better than Field Injection and Setter Injection.

So I've been trying to use Constructor Injection but it doesnt work.

I tried this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/something")
public class TestController {

    private final TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    public TestController (TestService testService){
         this.testService = testService;
    }

}
```

The console keeps throwing up bunch of error.

Which is BeanCreationException(Error creating bean with name...), AopConfigException(could not generate CGLIB...), IllegalArgumentException(Super class has no null constructor but no arguments were given).

Also, I've been trying to take off the 'final' and '@Autowired'. It's same. Doesnt work.

- these are how my project works..

```
1.
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/something")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/happy.do")
    public ModelAndView happything(){
        
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

       List<HashMap<String, Object>> happyListMap = testService.getHappyList();

       mav.addObject("happyListMap", happyListMap);
       mav.setViewName("world/happy/list");
       return mav;
    }

}

2.
public interface TestService {

    List<HashMap<String, Object>> getHappyList();

}

3.
@Service("TestService")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Autowired
    private TestMapper testMapper;

    @Autowired
    private HelpMapper helpMapper;

    @Override
    public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getHappyList(){

        int happyPoint = helpMapper.selectHowMuchHappyYouAre();

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> happyListMap = testMapper.selectHappyList(happyPoint);

        return happyListMap;
    }

}

4.
@Mapper("TestMapper")
public interface TestMapper {

    List<HashMap<String, Object>> selectHappyList(int happyPoint);

}

5.
testMapper.xml - myBatis

/* select query */
```

It's not supposed to work on spring 3.2.9? Should I just use Field Injection?

(Additing, the project can't use Lombok.)

Comment: You also need a default no-args constructor. apparently you somehow have something that tries to create a proxy for your controller. In this version you still need a no-args constructor for that.

Comment: @M. Deinum thank you for your comment. Could you expain more? you mean this 'NoArgsConstructor' annotation from lombok or? I also tried additing a default constructor under Autowired field. Like public TestController(){}. But as soon as I typed, there were some comments and warning sign(red circle with X sign) poped up. Sorry Im a baby developer..

Comment: No I'm not referring to Lombok (I walk around it as much as I can as it introduces more issues then it solves imho). As your field is `final` you need to assign it in your default contructor to `null` or invoke the other constructor with `null`.

Comment: Spring Framework latest release is already 6. So 3.2.9 is really an ancient one.

Comment: @M. Deinum um.. sorry It's too hard to understand without code.. But I'll try it. Thank you

Comment: @Horsing I know but this project is not a toy project for practicing or something like really mine. So I can't change that version easy. Maybe I could suggest to my team..

Comment: If you don't understand what a no-args default constructor is in java you have other problems then this code. I would strongly suggest to learn java first.

Comment: @M.Deinum I really agree.. I need to study harddddddd  Anyway it finally works!!!! Thank youuuuuuuu!

Comment: You really need to as you seem to seriously lack basic understanding on how java works and what things mean. Resulting in us (for free) doing your work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an ancient and unsupported version of Spring, which I highly recommend to upgrade to something that is supported (like 5.3.x or even the 6 although that last one might be a bridge too far).

The error tells you what is wrong, albeit a bit of a cryptic one.

```
BeanCreationException(Error creating bean with name...), AopConfigException(could not generate CGLIB...), IllegalArgumentException(Super class has no null constructor but no arguments were given).
```

The `null constructor` is a default no-args constructor as that is still needed in this version of Spring. The proxy needs a no-args constructor, so you need to add it. (This restriction has been lifted in later versions of Spring).

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/something")
public class TestController {

    private final TestService testService;

    public TestController() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Autowired
    public TestController (TestService testService){
         this.testService = testService;
    }

}
```

The controller above has a no-args constructor added, as your field is `final` you need to assign a value to it. I find it always better to chain the constructor and thus call `this(null)` which will invoke the `TestController(TestService testService)` constructor with a `null` value.

However the fact that you need this constructor highlights, imho, a bigger issue you have and that is that you are using AOP to apply some logic to classes. It appears to me, without knowing what you are doing, that you are applying it too broadly.

Comment: YOU ARE MY ANGEL ‍♀️ THANK YOU S2

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are using @Service or @Component annotation on TestService class.

And also check that TestService class have no argument constructor that means default constructor without any argument.

Comment: I did check and ..  when I typed no-args constructor on TestService and TestServiceImpl, it makes this error 'The blank final field mapper may not have been initialized'. I edited my question, could you please check again if you dont mind? I added my project's process(?)

Comment: @tinaMarina: read MDeinums comment again, he told you how to solve this, assign null to the fields in the no-arg constructor.